# How to solve this performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: problem?

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller, which calls performSelector:withObject:afterDelay. However, if I remove that view controller right after calling this, my app crashes as soon as the system tries to perform the delayed selector on that (deleted) view controller.

Now how can I go about this? I *need* to get rid of the view controller to save memory, so there's no way to let it hang around.

Any way to cancel a delayed perform selector before it performs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use an `NSTimer` instead. You can simply `invalidate` the timer to make sure it will never be called after the `UIViewController` has gone away. A good moment to `invalidate` the timer is for example in `viewWillDisappear:`.

This does mean that the timer is *owned* by the view controller. But that is a good design anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform a selector on a deleted object, you either need to have the object around, or do the work with some other smaller object that you can have hanging around.

To cancel there is a [cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:) or [cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:) method.

Comment: You can perform a selector on an object that is about to be deleted by  doing something like `[someObject performSelector: @selector(foo:) withObject: someObject afterDelay: 1.0]`. In that case `someObject` will be retained and released around the execution of that selector.

Comment: Right, but in that case the object isn't deleted, it's about to be deleted.